# Exported UTI for package/bundle

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle, uti

My Cocoa document-based app opens and writes custom packages/bundles.

Is this considered a proprietary format that needs to be exported via Exported UTIs (`UTExportedTypeDeclarations`)?

If so, what should be the values for:

- Conforms To (`UTTypeConformsTo`)
- Mime Types (`public.mime-type`)
- Pboard Types (`com.apple.nspboard-type`)
- OS Types (`com.apple.ostype`)

Finally, does the Exported UTI identifier (`UTTypeIdentifier`) need to be the same value than the Document Type identifier (`LSItemContentTypes`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trial-and-error findings:

> Is this considered a proprietary format that needs to be exported via Exported UTIs (`UTExportedTypeDeclarations`)?

Yes. While I couldn't find any explicit mention of this in the documentation, exporting the type was necessary for Finder to treat the directories as packages.

> - Conforms To (`UTTypeConformsTo`)

`com.apple.package` ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1))

> - Mime Types (`public.mime-type`)

Empty. Directories don't have a Mime Type?

> - Pboard Types (`com.apple.nspboard-type`)

Empty. Pboard Types are deprecated?

> - OS Types (`com.apple.ostype`)

No clue.

> Finally, does the Exported UTI identifier (`UTTypeIdentifier`) need to
>   be the same value than the Document Type identifier
>   (`LSItemContentTypes`)?

Yes, but I couldn't find any explicit mention of this in the documentation.